# how to extract asp .net control (Textbox) from .ascx.cs to another class and change the control attribute <ENABLE> to true

Tags: c#, asp.net

**my scenario:** I have more dropdown lists, when you click the dropdown list including with "Other" this word. my textbox enable attribute will be true otherwise it will be false (default). currently, I ran into a problem is I want to use one method to do this. when all dropdown lists was selected, it will call the same function and do the same thing. but I can't (1) Get the current dropdown list ID and even I got the drop-down list id, I cannot change the textbox ENABLE attribute to true. Thanks

***.ascx.cs***

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                <div class="formGreyBg">
                    <div>
                        <asp:Label ID="panellblS2Heading" runat="server" Font-Size="Larger" Font-Bold="True" CssClass="formHeading"></asp:Label><br />
                        <asp:Label ID="panellblS2Description" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" CssClass="formDescription"></asp:Label>
                    </div>

                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div class="formRow__underline formRow">
                        <div style="vertical-align: top" class="formRowLabelWrapper">
                            <asp:Label ID="panellblListedEntity" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" CssClass="formLabel"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div style="vertical-align: top" class="formRowInputWrapper">
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPanelddlListedEntity" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" Visible="true"
                            RenderMode="Inline">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="panelddlListedEntity" runat="server" Width="510" CssClass="formInput" 
                                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="panelddlListedEntity_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList><br/><br/>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="paneltbListedEntity" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>                                       
                                </ContentTemplate>
                                <Triggers>
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="panelddlListedEntity" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                                </Triggers>                                    
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
         </asp:Panel>
```

***Another class:***

```
protected void panelddlListedEntity_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //DropDownList dropDownList = (DropDownList)sender;

        if (panelddlListedEntity.SelectedValue.Contains("Other"))
        {                
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();

            textBox.ID = dropDownList.ID.ToString().Replace("ddl", "tb");
            textBox.Enabled = true;
            TextBox control = (TextBox)this.Page.LoadControl(@"~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/15/FRC.WB/Report/ReportUserControl.ascx").FindControl(dropDownList.ID.ToString().Replace("ddl", "tb"));
            //control.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
            paneltbListedEntity.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using WebForms in 2021? It's been effectively obsolete since 2008.

Comment: I only see one dropdown list and one text box? Is there some repeater, listview or some such that you left out here? Why not use the dropdown list selected index change  event to enable/disable the text box? I only see one text box here called paneltbListedEntity